# How to modify the name of a file with a number in the title?

Tags: python

I have some files where their names look like this:

```
AES_Trace=1149990_key=8f9a79d1a94d99a1b5806e803eac1b48_Plaintext=5321b7a34af144c03dbd66bbc61fdc53_Ciphertext=c2684c4713f2f46cb9e2d256c72b15ec.npy
```

I try to modify the name of each file, I need to put the  number at 49990:

```
  import os
    path_For_Numpy_Files='C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\tt'
    os.chdir(path_For_Numpy_Files)
    list_files_Without_Sort=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    list_files_Sorted=sorted((list_files_Without_Sort),key=os.path.getmtime)
    for file in list_files_Sorted:
            start = file[0:file.index("Trace=")+6]
            end = file[file.index("_key"):]
            num = file[len(start): file.index(end)]
            if num>400000:
               print (num)
               new_name= start
               new_name = start + str(int(num) - int('1100000')) + end
               print('\n'.join([start, end, num, new_name]))
    os.rename(os.path.join(path_For_Numpy_Files, file), os.path.join(path_For_Numpy_Files, new_name))
```

But instead substraction I have an addition: the new name is:

```
 -2249990   

AES_Trace=-2249990_key=8f9a79d1a94d99a1b5806e803eac1b48_Plaintext=5321b7a34af144c03dbd66bbc61fdc53_Ciphertext=c2684c4713f2f46cb9e2d256c72b15ec.npy
```

So, How to resolve this problem please? 
What I expect to have is: `49990`

Comment: I guess you have to add escape-characters in the string containing the file name. Try adding backslashes before the characters _, =, and -. Maybe the = sign is ok, but I am not sure.

Comment: value of `new_name` is: `AES_Trace=49990_key=8f9a79d1a94d99a1b5806e803eac1b48_Plaintext=5321b7a34af144c03dbd66bbc61fdc53_Ciphertext=c2684c4713f2f46cb9e2d256c72b15ec.npy` when I test this against the example `file` value.

Comment: @David Zemens ,It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Before your `os.rename` add a print statement like: `print('\n'.join([start, end, num, new_name]))` and let's see what you get. Please update your question to show the results, as they will not fit nicely in the comments.

Comment: It makes just the addition.

Comment: I don't understand what "makes just the addition" means. Can you update your question please?

Comment: I means That I have an addition in the number of my file instead of having substraction.

Comment: I will ask you one more time to please **update your question** to show the results of that print statement.  Please also indicate what the *expected* value should be.

Comment: @DavidZemens Could you please take a look at the edited question?

Comment: Please also indicate what the expected value should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I test this on a single example as you provided

```
file = 'AES_Trace=1149990_key=8f9a79d1a94d99a1b5806e803eac1b48_Plaintext=5321b7a34af144c03dbd66bbc61fdc53_Ciphertext=c2684c4713f2f46cb9e2d256c72b15ec.npy'
def foo(file=file):
    start = file[0:file.index("Trace=")+6]
    end = file[file.index("_key"):]
    num = file[len(start): file.index(end)]
    if num>400000:
        new_name= start  # This line is not needed, it is overwritten by next line
        new_name = start + str(int(num) - int('1100000')) + end

    return {'start':start,'end':end,'num':num,'new_name':new_name}
```

The resulting output is:

```
>>>print(foo())

{'new_name': 'AES_Trace=49990_key=8f9a79d1a94d99a1b5806e803eac1b48_Plaintext=5321b7a34af144c03dbd66bbc61fdc53_Ciphertext=c2684c4713f2f46cb9e2d256c72b15ec.npy',
 'start': 'AES_Trace=', 
 'num': '1149990', 
 'end': '_key=8f9a79d1a94d99a1b5806e803eac1b48_Plaintext=5321b7a34af144c03dbd66bbc61fdc53_Ciphertext=c2684c4713f2f46cb9e2d256c72b15ec.npy'}
```